# Jetpack Compose: How to add different amount of spacings to different contentTypes in LazyColumn?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a `LazyColumn` that displays numerous views with distinct `contentType` values, (`viewType` in the terminology of the `RecyclerView`).

Let's consider that this is my `LazyColumn`:

```
LazyColumn {
   items(itemsOfContentType1.size) {
       Content1Item(itemsOfContentType1[it])
   }
   items(itemsOfContentType2.size) {
       Content2Item(itemsOfContentType2[it])
   }
   items(itemsOfContentType3.size) {
       Content3Item(itemsOfContentType3[it]) // Want to add a spacer between these items!
   }
}
```

My objective is to have no spacing between items with `contentType=1` and `contentType=2`, while introducing an `8dp` gap between items with `contentType=3`.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented a workaround to wrap my items in a `Column` to add spacing between these items like this:

```
LazyColumn {
   items(itemsOfContentType1.size) { index ->
       Content1Item(itemsOfContentType1[index])
   }
   items(itemsOfContentType2.size) { index ->
       Content2Item(itemsOfContentType2[index])
   }
   items(itemsOfContentType3.size) { index ->
       Column {
           if (index > 0) {
               Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp)) // Adding spacer between items
           }
           Content3Item(itemsOfContentType3[it])
       }
   }
}
```

This solution aligns perfectly with my desired outcome. However, I'm wondering whether there might be a simpler way to implement this logic.